# Lists of linguistic resources

Tags: reference-request, corpora, online-resources

In the interest of cultivating a professional, academic community, I posted [this question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/112/42) on Meta. One comment was to open a community-wiki question inviting others to contribute to a list of academic sources in the field of linguistics.

There are lots of academic resources available online for us to read, enjoy, learn from and cite. Full-text journals, journal archives, corpora, studies...

I invite you to add the resources you know of, so we can put them all in one place.

The basics:

- [SIL's Topical index of linguistic resources on the Internet](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/topical.html)
- [Linguist List's list of journals](http://linguistlist.org/pubs/journals/browse-journals.cfm)
- [Linguist List's list of corpora](http://linguistlist.org/sp/GetWRListings.cfm?WRAbbrev=Texts)
- [Ethnologue](http://www.ethnologue.com/web.asp)

Answer (score 22):

**For citations:**

- [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/)
- LLBA
- ASC
- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/)

**Full-text journals:**

- [The Linguistics Journal](http://www.linguistics-journal.com/)
- Oxford's [Applied Linguistics](http://applij.oxfordjournals.org/content/by/year)
- [Journal of English Linguistics](http://eng.sagepub.com/)
- [International Journal of Applied Linguistics](http://www.wiley.com/bw/journal.asp?ref=0802-6106)
- MIT's [Computational Linguistics](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/loi/coli)
- [Diachronica: International Journal for Historical Linguistics](http://www.benjamins.com/#catalog/journals/dia/toc)
- [Language](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/language/)
- [SIL ebooks](http://www.sil.org/silepubs/index.asp?series=941)
- [The Association for Computational Linguistics](http://aclweb.org/anthology-new/) Anthology

**Corpora:**

- UPenn's [Linguistic Data Consortium](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/)
- [ICAME](http://icame.uib.no/), [Athel collection of corpora](http://www.athel.com/corpora.html)
- BYU's [corpora list](http://corpus.byu.edu/)
- [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) lexical corpus from Princeton. Widely used as a dictionary for word meanings/senses
- [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/) encyclopedic lexical corpus from Berkeley. Wordnet++, with contexts and metaphor
- [Michigan Corpus of Academic Spoken English](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/c/corpus/corpus?c=micase;page=simple) (MICASE)
- [English Gigaword](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2003T05): Four distinct international sources of English newswire (Agence France Press English Service, Associated Press Worldstream English Service, The New York Times Newswire Service, The Xinhua News Agency English Service)

**Other primary sources:**

- MIT's [foreign language newspaper collection](http://libguides.mit.edu/flnewspapers)
- SIL's [Language and Culture Documentation and Description](http://www.sil.org/silepubs/index.asp?series=947)
- [American English Dialect Recordings](http://memory.loc.gov/ammem/collections/linguistics/) @ Library of Congress
- [International Dialects of English Archive](http://web.ku.edu/~idea/)
- [George Mason English Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/) (foreign accents and native local accents)
- British Library [Accents and Dialects Archival Sound Recordings](http://sounds.bl.uk/BrowseCategory.aspx?category=Accents-and-dialects)

**MOOCs:**

- Adelaide University [Language Revival: Securing the Future of Endangered Languages](https://www.edx.org/course/language-revival-securing-future-adelaidex-lang101x-0)
- Universiteit Leiden, Meertens instituut [Miracles of Human Language: An Introduction to Linguistics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/human-language)
- University of Michigan [Introduction to Natural Language Processing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/natural-language-processing)
- University of Houston [The Bilingual Brain](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bilingual)
- Marburg University [The Virtual Linguistics Campus](https://www.youtube.com/user/LinguisticsMarburg)
- MIT [OpenCourseware, Linguistics and Philosophy](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/linguistics-and-philosophy/)

**Other resources:**

- Max Planck Institute's [Field Manuals and Stimulus Materials](http://fieldmanuals.mpi.nl/)
- UIowa's [Phonetics Flash Animation Project](http://www.uiowa.edu/~acadtech/phonetics/)
- UCL's [IPA reference](http://www.langsci.ucl.ac.uk/ipa/)

Comment: You should check the box to make your answer community wiki, so that others can edit it.

Comment: I forgot when posting, so it's been flagged.

Comment: @Aaron If you didn't, also flag the question as Mod attention -> other and write that you're asking to make it CW. :)

Comment: @mollyocr if you edit it, you will find the cw checkbox in the bottom left of the edit field..

Comment: @LouisRhys Nope. =\ I don't know if it's a reputation thing, but I don't have the box in editing, only in asking a question.

Comment: Eh, it's CW now. Edit away...

Answer (score 7):

The databases [UPSID](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/faciliti/sales/software.htm) for phonemic inventories (web interface [here](http://web.phonetik.uni-frankfurt.de/upsid.html)) and [WALS](http://wals.info/) for structural properties in general. The latter allows easy exporting of data in an easily parsable format (it's also possible in the former, but it requires some twiddling).

Answer (score 5):

## List of resources

- [PHOIBLE](http://phoible.org/) phonological database
- [Surrey Morphology Group](http://www.smg.surrey.ac.uk/databases/) databases
- [Konstanz Universals Archive](http://typo.uni-konstanz.de/archive/nav/browse.php?number=1&PHPSESSID=3h2agvob37fnemalfkqbnn18fjoq4jtm)
- [Encyclopedia of Linguistic Laws and the Laws in Quantitative Linguistics](http://lql.uni-trier.de/index.php/Main_Page)
- [Glottolog](https://glottolog.org/)

Answer (score 3):

**[CLARIN](https://www.clarin.eu/)** (European Research Infrastructure for Language Resources and Technology) entry points:

- [Virtual Language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu/): A search engine for language resources
- [TeLeMaCo](https://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/): Teaching and Learning Materials Collection, a collaborative portal to teaching and learning materials
- [WebLicht](http://weblicht.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/weblichtwiki/index.php/Main_Page): A web based chaining tools for language processing (needs a federated account for login; currently available languages are English and German)

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford Reference Encyclopedia of Linguistics, the Elsevier Encyclopedia of Language and Linguistics, the International Encyclopedia of Linguistics, and any Oxford, Routledge, or Wiley-Blackwell handbook on any topic in linguistics.

Answer (score -2):

Good night! 
I find all the contributions very useful. Thanks a lot for sharing.
I suggest you to check the following links:

https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=gPbQyRdnM18C&hl=es-419

https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=pxJGet3pKdoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=introduction+to+semantics&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0ItVU5rAFeWb3AXCtYCYDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=introduction%20to%20semantics&f=false

Comment: You can improve this answer by adding some information to the pure links (that might get stale anytime), such as Author, title, publisher and year, and maybe a short comment on why they are good resources.